# Windows Direct Sound is causing sound distortion in SDRSharp

Tags: windows, audio

I posted my question few days ago on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/comments/12j7uli/what_is_causing_this_sound_distortion_in_sdrsharp/) asking about `SDRSharp` distortion that happens after few seconds, as is shown in a video of the link above. I figured out that the problem is caused when I set sound output to `Windows Direct Sound`. With `MME` has no problem. But MME is old and I would like to use `WDS` instead. It looks like full buffer? OR something like that? I would like to know way to resolve this issue, maybe reinstall or? Also I have no problems with other apps, like VLC, or browser.